# Howto setup a python virtualenv on your system, and connect it to your addon

Tags: python, add-on

I am using Blender 2.83 on ubuntu.

I am developing an addon that I am very happy with, and would like to include other 3rd party libraries such as scipy and vectormath. In the most ambitious goal, i would like to merge other projects into my Blender addon, and port all the work that has been done previously into the Blender scripting tab, replacing lots of old ugly visualizations and crappy mesh operations with the awesome Blender functions.

In order to do this, I have found only one sane solution online. Start blender with the PYTHONPATH set to a local interpreter, combined with the proper CLI command (--python-use-system-env).

However, I dont want some hack that will only work on my machine. I do not want to go by trial and error finding what versions of different libraries needs to be present. So, my questions:

1. How do I make a requirements.txt or similar from the bundled python interpreter, so I know how make a local virtualenv that will not break Blender?
2. Is there some built-in function in Blender to accomodate what i want to do, so that I could actually deploy this addon to wider audience, without it coming with extra instructions on how to install?

Comment: @Robert Gützkow 's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181953/35559) may not answer, but will help fill you in...

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at his repository now. I may end up doing something like that, especially since I now have a great starting place with his code. However, it corresponds to modifying the bundled python environment, without any kind of virtualenv. I wonder if changing the virtualenv could work dynamically? This could be a workaround, resulting in very slow execution times for the addon however. This would be way to work with another version of Numpy say, without breaking other functionality.